# WPF Specifying How Columns Are Generated When They Are Binded

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` that gets binded by various `DataTable`s. The nullable `boolean` columns get converted into `DataGridCheckboxColumn`. is there a way to convert this to a text column that shows yes, no, not available?

Comment: I have never done something like this but it sounds like a job for a `TemplateSelector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna keep the auto generating behavior you can subscribe to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event from the `DataGrid` and change the generated `DataGridColumn`

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn dataGridCheckBoxColumn)
    {
        Binding binding = (Binding)dataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding;
        binding.Converter = new BooleanToStringConverter(); //Converter Klaus Gütter mentioned
        e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = dataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header,
            Binding = binding
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could craete a value converter and specify it the binding as Converter.

```
public class BooleanToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(string) && value is bool?)
        {
            var b = (bool?)value;
            if (!b.HasValue)
                return "not available";
            return b.Value ? "yes" : "no";
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // implement it if you need two-way binding
        throw new NotImpementedException();
    }
}
```

In XML, create an instance of it in the Resources

```
<local:BooleanToStringConverter x:Key="BooleanToStringConverter" />
```

and add it to the binding

```
Binding={"Binding MyColumn, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}}"
```